# VBA get list of available languages on current machine

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, keyboard-layout

I have a muulti-language Access application that needs access to languages/keyboard layouts installed on the machine. I have certain fields that accept input in various languages. I would like to be able to change the active language/keyboard layout when these fields are entered and exited.

I'm sure that there is some sort of windows API for this but I haven't been able to turn anything up. I would be happy for any code examples, links or anything that could get me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the active keyboard layout using the [Keyboard Input Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468859%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The functions you should look at are:

- [LoadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646305%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [ActivateKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [UnloadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646324%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [GetKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646296%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [GetKeyboardLayoutName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646298%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [GetKeyboardLayoutList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646297%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

You can find a list of [Locale IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx) on MSDN or download from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965%28PROT.10%29.aspx). You can get the currently installed locales using the [EnumSystemLocales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317828%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. I can't vouch for the quality of the code, but here are some examples of using these functions:

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/locale/enumsystemlocales.htm

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=22694

http://www.ex-designz.net/apidetail.asp?api_id=499

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?p=1313750